# Python import similar to Django settings file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a *.py file to take variables from and use them across multiple imports in my python application, similar to how a Django settings file works.

An example settings file:

```
DB_NAME = 'foo'
DB_TABLE = 'bar'
#Lots of other variable names and values here
```

The benefit is that I can load different settings very quickly this way. I can reference a sort of global "DB_NAME" wherever I want without having specific objects to deal with.

The drawback is that I have to change the import statement in every file that has to import them.

Can I set it up so that I import the file once and then reference a generic import to get all of these values?

Or is there a much better way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The problem stems from having multiple settings files. I would have to import settings.py for one file, or if I want a different settings file, I would need to change all the import statements to reference test_settings.py, etc..

I don't want to manually change the import locations in order to change what is imported across the entire application.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Each Python module is just a namespace. If you have something like mypacakge/settings.py just write `from . import settings` and then access your options like `settings.DB_NAME`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your answer. I have updated my question. Please let me know if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create our own config.py  file in a folder

```
settings = {}
settings['server'] = '172.16.150.106:1433'
settings['user'] = 'pyadmin'
settings['password'] = 'admin'
settings['db'] = 'SQLSERV_2005'
```

open shell (ipython)

```
In [1]: from config import settings

In [2]: print settings
{'password': 'admin', 'db': 'SQLSERV_2005', 'user': 'pyadmin', 'server': '172.16.150.106:1433'}
```

don't forget your __init__.py file !

Answer (score 2):

You can use module `__builtin__`:

File a.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import __builtin__
import b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import conf
    __builtin__.__dict__["CONF"] = conf

    print "IN A: %s" % CONF.VAR

    b.test_conf()
```

File b.py:

```
def test_conf():
   print "IN B: %s" % CONF.VAR
```

File conf.py:

VAR = "VAL"

So basically you need to setup an element in builtin dict once and then access it in any other loaded modules by name.

Comment: Don't do that unless you have a very good reason to..  That way lies madness.

Comment: If used with care it'is perfectly legal and solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to have a globally available module.

There are a few ways of doing this, as set out in the [Python module search path docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). Essentially, if you can put your global module under your `sys.path` search path, you can access it anywhere on your machine in your user environment. (Note that you can add modules to sys.path for wsgi servers too.)

I add some modules to my PYTHONPATH environment variable through my `.bashrc` file; eg:

```
PYTHONPATH=~/projects/pyutil/:$PYTHONPATH
```

You can also add to the search path of any python program prior to importing modules by adding to `sys.path` before imports take place.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem stems from having multiple settings files

If you want to be able to alias multiple modules, there's a couple of solutions:

```
try: 
    import test_settings as settings
except ImportError:
    import default_settings as settings
```

Note that you don't have to use the presence/absence of the modules, you can use any flow control you like to select the right `import` statement.

Also, as suggested, `PYTHONPATH` can/should be used to aim at different settings:

```
   # code just does "import settings" and there's a settings.py in each /opt/{test,default}_settings
   PYTHONPATH=/opt/test_settings ./my_app
   PYTHONPATH=/opt/default_settings ./my_app
```

And finally, consider `distutils` to make this a truly reproducible solution -- distribute the different settings as different distributions which provide the same package name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean by "use any flow control to select the right import statement". If all of the settings files exist in the directory, wouldn't it always default to the first one listed?

Comment: The `try:`/`except:` example will first search for a file called `test_settings.py` and if it's not there will look for `default_settings.py`.  But you could use `if is_monday: import test_settings as settings ; else: import default_settings as settings`